# jquery .serialize() select multiple tag name for array is being encoded

Tags: php, jquery, url-encoding

I have a select multiple tag with a name `city[]`.  The `[]` brackets are supposed to signify an array in the url query string for the PHP later.

I'm using jQuery .serialize() to get the form value to build a query string for an AJAX call.  However, it looks like .serialize() is encoding the URL and not writing the brackets

I should get

```
index.php?city[]=METROPLOIS&city[]=GOTHAM
```

Instead I'm getting

```
index.php?city%5B%5D=METROPLOIS&city%5B%5D=GOTHAM
```

Is there a way to make it stop encoding for just the name? There may be some instances where the city name has a space, so I'll still need it to encode that.

Comment: why can't you just decode it on the other side? instead of just trying to prevent the encoding

Comment: No for security reason you can't prevent browser to encode the url. you can replace each [] into for example "brckt" and when you get that replace it with [] again.

Comment: What's the status of this?

Comment: Sorry, I will post answer later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just a bit confused since you may be unfamiliar with URL escaping.

But, this works perfectly in PHP. For instance, `print_r($_GET)` will output:

```
Array
(
    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => METROPLOIS
            [1] => GOTHAM
        )

)
```

Being `city` interpreted correctly as an array and containing the expected values. Since, `city%5B%5D` is a valid URL encoded string for `city[]`.